# Using ~/.ssh/authorized_keys for non-root users?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a bunch of users that are each connected to a directory in the home folder.

Any way to set this up so that every time I create a new user and directory it's linked to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys so I don't have to use a password or reconfigure anything for each user?

Comment: How about http://serverfault.com/questions/330227/system-wide-authorized-keys